# Need help in Python3

Tags: sockets, networking, python-3.x, socketexception

I have the below code that i am trying the run using python3.2 interpreter.

```
import socket   #for sockets
import sys  #for exit
#from UserString import MutableString

#create an INET, STREAMing socket
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error:
    print ('Failed to create socket')
    sys.exit()

print ('Socket Created')

host = 'www.google.com';
port = 80;

try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname( host )

except socket.gaierror:
    #could not resolve
    print ('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')
    sys.exit()

#Connect to remote server
s.connect((remote_ip , port))

print ('Socket Connected to ' + host + ' on ip ' + remote_ip)

#Send some data to remote server
message = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"

try :
    #Set the whole string
    s.sendall(message.encode())
except socket.error:
    #Send failed
    print ('Send failed')
    sys.exit()

print ('Message send successfully')

#Now receive data

messageParts = []
remaining = 4096
chunk = s.recv(remaining)
messageParts.append(chunk)

while (len(chunk) > 0):

    chunk = s.recv(remaining)
    messageParts.append(chunk.decode())

finalMessage = b"".join(messageParts)

print('Printing the html contents ...')
print(finalMessage)
```

Upon running the above code, with python version 3.2, i get the below error:

```
Socket Created
Socket Connected to www.google.com on ip 74.125.201.147
Message send successfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestMainServerV2.py", line 73, in <module>
    finalMessage = b"".join(messageParts)
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected bytes, str found
```

Could anybody let me know what is the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
messageParts.append(chunk.decode())
```

is appending `str`s to `messageParts`.

```
chunk = s.recv(remaining)
messageParts.append(chunk)
```

is appending `bytes` to `messageParts`. (Everything that comes through a socket is `bytes` so `chunk` is a `bytes` object.)

Especially in Python3, one should never mix `str`s and `bytes`.

```
b"".join(messageParts)
```

raises a TypeError since `b"".join` expects only `bytes`.

---

You can avoid the problem by not decoding `chunk`. Use

```
messageParts.append(chunk)
```

instead of

```
messageParts.append(chunk.decode())
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Could you please let me know how i can correct the above code?